# Rails Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a Rails rookie.

I practice CRUD, but have an error that occurs when I start rails server.

I have tried to search the solution but haven't found anything.

The mysql user name is 'jack' and the password is '1'.

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

```
Mysql2::Error - Access denied for user 'jack'@'localhost' (using password: YES):
mysql2 (0.3.13) lib/mysql2/client.rb:58:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `mysql2_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/Users/jackhou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/Users/jackhou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:792:in `current_version'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:800:in `needs_migration?'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:379:in `check_pending!'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:366:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1484653479291478227__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
airbrake (3.1.14) lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
airbrake (3.1.14) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
airbrake (3.1.14) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/jackhou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/jackhou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/jackhou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

database.yml

```
development: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: groupme_development
  host: localhost
  username: jack
  password: "1"

test: &TEST
  <<: *default
  database: groupme_test
```

Comment: Can you please post your database.yml file as well?

Comment: @jvperrin ok, I edit!

Comment: Does "jack" have all privliges on database ?

Comment: @Vucko sorry,I don't know how to confirm the privilege. Does it have the way to confirm it or root the username?

Comment: on the command line try: `mysql -u jack -p -h localhost` and see if the password works there. If it doesn't, then the MySQL database user is not setup correctly.

Comment: Try using the "root" user instead of "jack". If the "root" works, then you didn't grant privileges to "jack".

Comment: @ChristophEicke I change to root, but it still show Mysql2::Error - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

Comment: @JackHou: does it work on the command line? You can also try to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`...